# Setting up Umbraco as a subsite inside another Website (Virtual Directory converted to application) in IIS

Tags: umbraco

I have configured an umbraco website (v-7.2.4) in IIS successfully and is working fine. Now, i have a requirement to add this Umbraco Website to be inside a virtual directory converted to application in another parent website. But there is an issue with the paths configuration. Media folder and all the JS get requests are being sent to **root/media** and **root/umbraco** which is invalid since the actual paths are now **root/virtualdirectory/media** and **root/virtualdirectory/umbraco**. When umbraco dashboard is opened it shows empty screen on Logging in and then redirects to login page after some time. There are some 404 errors in console which i reckon are the reason of the issue and are being produced due to wrong paths setting.

Kindly tell me how am i supposed to set these path values since i am not able to find anything in Web.config and UmbracoSettings.config.

Console Errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:10/umbraco/developer/RelationTypes/TreeMenu/ActionDeleteRelationType.js?cdv=1915091649
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:10/umbraco/developer/RelationTypes/TreeMenu/ActionNewRelationType.js?cdv=1915091649
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (You must login to view this resource.) localhost:10/blog/umbraco/ServerVariables?umb__rnd=64cfd8d1&umb__rnd=undefined.undefined
No url found for api name legacyTreeJs angular.min.js?cdv=1915091649:63
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS localhost:10/blog/umbraco#/login/false
GET localhost:10/blog/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js?cdv=1915091649:106

Answer (score 0):

Open up your "UmbracoSettings.config" file in the "/config" folder and ensure that the "ResolveUrlsFromTextString" setting is set to true. That SHOULD do the trick (you may need to restart the app pool for that to take effect).

Comment: Hi @Tim. Thanks for the reply. I already have tried your mentioned workaround but it didn't work.

Comment: You can set the umbraco back office path in the web.config file (umbracoPath in appSettings), does setting that work?

Comment: umbracoPath is for the admin panel. see http://redino.net/blog/2013/08/umbraco-admin-url/

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI there is an official bug raised about this issue.  You can see it here: [issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6346#tab=Comments](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6346#tab=Comments)

I've done some of my own debugging and will update that ticket with what I've found